# Rotation animation is not spinning the asset in center point

Tags: android, mobile, android-animation

I'm trying to rotate a round button when is pressed.My problem is the button doesn't rotate around it's own centre. Followed other examples but the outcome is the same. Here is my code:

rotate.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<rotate
    android:duration="1500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

and in the class I'm using the animation:

```
Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.animator.rotate);

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

Log.e(TAG, "event:::" + event.getAction());

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
     view.startAnimation(animRotate);
   view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_asset);
} else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
    view.clearAnimation();
   view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_asset);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check your drawable is it proper if both width and height is same you get the exact center else you will feel its not rotating on center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to rotate a View

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
view.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required 
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```